# Math operators parameters

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-grouping

I wanted to know if we can use math operators in the parameter of the report.

I have a parameter called "EMP_Attendance".

I want to have the parameter to display and Run the report with values

Parameter:

EMP_Attendance

```
           = 100.00%
           <100.00% and >=90.00%
           <90.00% and >=80.00%
           <80.00%
```

the Report should run according to this value

Comment: Could you eleborate a bit more? Your question is sorta hard to understand.

Comment: I want to show the list of employees in the report depending on their attendance % for the year. The attendance is calculated from the query itself. So i will have to display for example:                  <100.00% and >=90.00% : It has to show me all the employees having less than 100.% attendance but greater than 90.00%

Comment: Do you have a parameter the user is to select, one of the three above or is your report needed go be grouped by a field?

Comment: The user should be able to select one of the 4 options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you would add 4 available values to your parameter with a label of "100%" etc. and values of 1,2,3,4.

Then you have 2 options to filter.

1. You can add something like this to your query:

   ```
   SELECT case when EMP_Attendance = 100 then 1 
   when EMP_Attendance <100 and EMP_Attendance >=90.00% then 2
   when EMP_Attendance <90 and EMP_Attendance >=80 then 3
   else 4 end as AttendanceGroup
   WHERE AttendanceGroup = @AttendanceParameter
   ```
2. The other option is to keep the query as is so that it returns all the data to the report. Right-click on the table and go to its properties. Go to Filters. Add filters here to compare your parameter with the EMP_Attendance value.

Answer (score 1):

This is not natively possible but there is a slight work around.

1. Create a visible parameter with your four options above.
2. Create two internal parameters that are populated by two dummy sqls, one `lower` and one `upper`.
3. Make the queries produce the appropriate upper and lower limits based on the users selection, e.g. If 100% is selected `lower` = 100 and `upper` = 101.
4. Filter the dataset by these two limits.

Comment: Can you please elaborate...and how is it gonna effect the main query

Comment: It will filter the main query to what the user selects for your original parameter.

Comment: The other option is to put this filter in the query itself similarly to Stevens answer